# Mute all users in a channel from reaction

Tags: node.js, discord, discord.js

I was trying to make a gaming bot for my gaming server with friends and i wanted to make a muting bot for amoung us how do i make this code work ive tried grabbing some code from reaction tickets and see if i could turn it into muting the entire channel instead of making a channel here is the code  i tried catching the error and i got no error

```
client.on('message', async message => {
    if(message.content.startsWith(prefix + "AUStart")) {
        const muteembed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
        .setTitle('Amoung Us Mute')
        .setImage('https://i.imgur.com/wc6MmgF.jpg')
        const AUMessage = await message.channel.send(muteembed)
        await AUMessage.react(`❌`); // emojis are ❌  
        await AUMessage.react(``);
        await AUMessage.react(``)
    }
});

client.on('messageReactionAdd', async (reaction, user) => {
    if(user.reaction === "") {
        reaction.users.remove(user)

        if (message.member.voice.channel) {
            let channel = message.guild.channels.cache.get(message.member.voice.channel.id);
            for (const [memberID, member] of channel.members) {
              // I added the following if statement to mute everyone but the invoker:
              // if (member != message.member)
          
              // This single line however, nested inside the for loop, should mute everyone in the channel:
              member.voice.setMute(true);
            }
          } else {
            message.reply('You need to join a voice channel first!');
          }
    }
})
```

Comment: It'd be easier to fix the issue if you have a better idea where it is. Run it step by step in a debugger and look around at the variables and see if they're correct. I suspect this might have something to do with `.setMute`. Catch the error with `.setMute(true).error(console.error);`.

Comment: i did that but no error where else should i try .error(console.error);